# Django - Heroku postgres connection opens with each page refresh and does not close ever

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am using Django, heroku, websocket, AJAX, celery, postgres, consumer, asgi (uvicorn; tried Daphne also). **My problem is that after just a page refresh, new postgres connection would be created, and it doesn't go away even after long inactivity.** Soon with just refreshes my connections go over the top (20/20 on heroku). On local environment, no problem - connection does not add up no matter what I do. This happens only on heroku using heroku postgres (I'm using the default version).

What I've tried:

- I've checked pg_stat_activity. The connections are related to the corresponding view code that queries certain data.

```
for post in posts:
        temp_dict = defaultdict(list)
        recommendations_ordered = post.recommendations.all().order_by('created_at')
        ...and so on, including request.user.
```

If I have 15 connections, most of them are from this -- same query. One from request.user. All idle. These don't exist when I run pg_stat_activity on local postgres.

- I've set my database settings as:

```
if ENVIRONMENT == 'development':
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'redacted',
        'USER': 'redacted',
        'PASSWORD': 'redacted',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
    DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 0  
    DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
```

- I've added close.connection to the aforementioned view as well as tasks.
- Here's my procfile.

```
web: gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker decide.asgi:application
worker: celery -A decide worker -l info --pool=threads
```

What could be going on? I'd really appreciate help.

In case relevant:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0'),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}

if ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
    CACHES['default']['OPTIONS']['CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS'] = {"ssl": True}


# Cache settings
CACHE_TTL = 300 

# Use Django's cache API
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = "default"
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = CACHE_TTL
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ""


# Celery Configuration
if ENVIRONMENT == 'development':
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
else:  # production
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')  
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')  

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uncomment this line:

`django_heroku.settings(locals())`

.........I spent about 20 hours trying different things

Comment: See https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/41 (and also https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/56)

Comment: You don't show your dependencies so we can't know what `django_heroku` is for sure. But to Selcuk's point the original project has been abandoned. [`django-on-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/) is a fork that's still at least somewhat maintained.